# Why would my router randomly become unreachable under WPA2?

Tags: wireless-networking, airport

We just switched ISPs from AT&T DSL to Comcast.  AT&T had its own (horrifically bad) router, but with Comcast we're using my 802.11n Airport Extreme.  Unfortunately, the router randomly becomes unreachable.  I'm still shown as "connected", but I can't ping the router anymore.  This doesn't appear to happen when I've got WPA2 off, though I can't confirm for sure.  Any idea why this might happen, or what I can do to prevent it?  I would really prefer to be using WPA2 if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the router was on the other side of the kitchen wall behind the stove.  Large metal objects completely wreck the signal-to-noise ratios.  Moving the router so that it wasn't right next to the stove fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any wireless devices in range? A friend of mine had a similar situation, he never noticed that his internet only cut out when his cordless phone rang. The wireless signals were interfering.

Comment: +1, good troubleshooting first step.  i'd expect such interference to occur even with WPA2 off, but maybe non-WPA2 is more resilient.  changing channels (or even frequencies, if all wifi devices support both 2.4 & 5GHz) might help.

Comment: This happens even late at night when everything is off.  I've been running a continuous ping against the router and ping times vary wildly from sub 1ms to 25000ms.

Comment: The router tends to cut out when ping times are on the really high end of the spectrum.  I'm fairly sure the problem is just that the signal-to-noise ratio is getting really bad.  This is expected.  The problem is that it doesn't auto-reconnect after.  I have to manually turn wireless off and reconnect.